# Fetching Image from Server with a React Native App

Tags: react-native

I'm building a mobile app with a Springboot Rest API backend and a React-Native Frontend.
I'm able to upload a picture from the react-native API to Springboot API and to store it in my postgres database as byte[].
I'm able to retrieve this picture with a simple Get Request tested by Postman.
BUT I'm not able to fetch this image and to display it in my React Native app.

I understood there is a problem to use blob file immediately with react native but I didnt see how to handle it.

Here is my fetch function :

```js
export const getAquariumPicture = async (
  aquariumId: string
): Promise<ImageSourcePropType | any> => {
  const suffixUrl = "api/downloadAquariumPicture/";
  const urlService = urlServer + suffixUrl + aquariumId;
  try {
    const token = await getData("token");
    const response = await fetch(urlService, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: token
      }
    });
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

**how can I use this response to pass it as source in an Image balise ?**

Here how I'm trying to use the photo :

```js
  if (rootStore.tankStore.tankImageState === "pending") {
    rootStore.tankStore.storeGetImageTank();
  }
  const photo = rootStore.tankStore.tankPicture;
  console.log("photo = " + photo);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => choosePicture()}>
      <Image source={cameraIcon} style={styles.icon} />

      {photo != null ? (
        <Image source={photo} style={styles.photo} />
      ) : (
        <ActivityIndicator />
      )}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
```

Comment: Please add the code for your Image component and how you are adding it to the source of Image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact I found a solution :

```js
      <Image
        source={getAquariumImageSource(RootStore.tankStore.tankList[0].id)}
        style={styles.photo}
      />
      
      
      
      export const getAquariumImageSource = (id: string): ImageSourcePropType => {
  return {
    uri: `${urlServer}api/downloadAquariumPicture/${id}`,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Pragma: "no-cache",
      Authorization: RootStore.memberStore.token
    },
    cache: "reload"
  };
};
```